# Django - dynamic filtering multiple querysets

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset, django-filter

I want to make a monthly breakdown of expenses by type of expenses.
I would like to enter the start date and end date dynamically through the filter form, so that I don't have to duplicate the code for each month.

For each type of expense I created a separate queryset (more than 20).

Here is the view.py

```
def monthly_analysis_november(request):

    accountant = Expenses.objects\
    .filter(date__gte = "2023-11-01", date__lte = "2023-11-30", type_of_expense = "accountant expenses")\
    .annotate(price=Sum(F('quantity')*F('price_per_unit')))\
        .aggregate(total_accountant=Sum('price'))
        
    interest_rates = Expenses.objects\
    .filter(date__gte = "2023-11-01", date__lte = "2023-11-30", type_of_expense = "interest rates")\
    .annotate(price=Sum(F('quantity')*F('price_per_unit')))\
        .aggregate(total_interest_rates=Sum('price'))
        
    phones = Expenses.objects\
    .filter(date__gte = "2023-11-01", date__lte = "2023-11-30", type_of_expense = "phones")\
    .annotate(price=Sum(F('quantity')*F('price_per_unit')))\
        .aggregate(total_phones=Sum('price'))
        
    oil = Expenses.objects\
    .filter(date__gte = "2023-11-01", date__lte = "2023-11-30", type_of_expense = "oil")\
    .annotate(price=Sum(F('quantity')*F('price_per_unit')))\
        .aggregate(total_oil=Sum('price'))
        
    leasing = Expenses.objects\
    .filter(date__gte = "2023-11-01", date__lte = "2023-11-30", type_of_expense = "leasing")\
    .annotate(price=Sum(F('quantity')*F('price_per_unit')))\
        .aggregate(total_leasing=Sum('price'))
        
    other_expenses = Expenses.objects\
    .filter(date__gte = "2023-11-01", date__lte = "2023-11-30", type_of_expense = "other")\
    .annotate(price=Sum(F('quantity')*F('price_per_unit')))\
        .aggregate(total_other_expenses=Sum('price'))
    ...
```

Here is the model.py I've created

```
class Expenses(models.Model):
  date = models.DateField()
  place_of_expense = models.ForeignKey(ConstructionSite, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
  TYPE_OF_EXPENSE_CHOICES = (
    ("oil", "oil"),
    ("leasing", "leasing"),
    ("material", "material"),
    ("land leasing", "land leasing"),
    ("spare parts", "spare parts"),
    ("tools and equipment", "tools and equipment"),
    ("services", "services"),
    ("accountant expenses", "accountant expenses"),
    ("interest rates", "interest rates"),
    ("phones", "phones"),
    ("other", "other"),
    ...
  )
  type_of_expense = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=25, choices=IZBOR_VRSTE_TROSKA, default = "Gorivo")
  expense_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  unit = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=20, choices=IZBOR_JEDINICE_MERE, default = "l")
  quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  price_per_unit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm using django-filters in some other parts of the app, but here I couldn't implement it.
At this time, I have the same view function for each month, but that's a ton of duplicated code. The only differences are date__gte and date__lte.
Is there a possibility to do this using django-filters, or maybe some other way?

Comment: Hi, in your case you probably don't really need to run queries one after another. You can easily write a aggregation by expense in one query. Let me know if you want me to give you an example

Comment: Hi, thanks, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Great! See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't really need to run queries for each individual expense, since in your case they will be executed consequenlty and can take more time than you might expect.

Depending on your goal you probably might want to consider the following code:

```py
def monthly_analysis_november(request):
    result = dict(
        Expense.objects
            .filter(date__gte = "2023-11-01", date__lte = "2023-11-30")
            .values('type_of_expense')  # This two lines will make the grouping by `type_of_expense`
            .order_by('type_of_expense')
            .annotate(total=Sum(F('quantity')*F('price_per_unit')))  # Compute the sum
            .values_list('type_of_expense', 'total')  # Return expenses by type
    )

    # The result dictionary would looke like the following:
    # {"services": "xx.yy", "oil": "xx.yy", ...}
```

The idea is that you run one query against the Expense table with group by and SUM aggreation function.

I hope this answer help you. Let me know if you want me to explain the solution in details.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to implement it in my code and will get back to you.

Comment: That was very helpful. I've managed to implement it in my code with a few minor corrections, in order to apply the filter. I still need to have 3 or 4 querysets, because of different formula, calculations of salaries (different model), etc, but it's a lot better now.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [Djanog-filter documentations](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#declaring-filters) I think what you need to do to be able to use this package with `date__gte` is to create a filter class like so:

```
class ExpensesFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
date = django_filters.NumberFilter()
date__gt = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr='gt')
date__lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr='lt')
```

Comment: I've tried something like that, but I couldn't implement it in combination with aggregation/annotation.